# Error using BCP and hidden path to export data from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

When I use hidden path like `\\\twn-a110093\s$\SNData1.csv`, it does not work.

Error message:

> [Microsoft][SQL Native Client] Unable to open BCP host data-file

Perhaps the '$' char is not recognized? How do I fix this problem?

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp " select * from sfm.dbo.tblSNDataDetail " queryout "\\twn-a110093\s$\SNData1.csv" -c -t, -T -S TWN-SQL-01'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can't BCP data directly to UNC path, there will be double hop issue, you have to set up constrained delegation between 2 servers. What you need to do is to first BCP to your local drive, then move/copy file to UNC path, which is actually faster than you directly BCP to UNC path even you set it up correctly. Believe it or not, try it.

Comment: interesting... why would there be a double hop issue if the process is executing under the sql server service account?

Answer (score 0):

More likely a security issue:

"The Windows process spawned by xp_cmdshell has the same security rights as the SQL Server service account"

Be sure the SQL Server service account user has access to that path/file.

Comment: But I give "Account:Everyone" full control

Comment: On the file?  What about the permissions for the hidden share?

Comment: The same.It's "Account:Everyone" full control.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an UNC path in BCP command, and actually you directly create a file on drive root S$. It will involve security check. What you can try is:
1. First change the path from drive root folder to a sub folder like `\twn-a110093\s$\Test\SNData1.csv`
2. Give SQL Server service account write permission to folder 'test', if SQL Server running under NT Service, then you need to give Network Service account write permission to folder
3.If "twn-a110093" is not the same server which SQl Server located, then on the file share folder, you probably need to give 'everyone' full permission.
4. If all doesn't work, then first BCP out to local folder, then robocopy file to UNC Path, like @Guna said, that is better to directly write file to UNC path, that is true.

Comment: Good. But remember directly write file to UNC path is slower than first write file to local then copy file to UNC path.